# Right to Left jQuery Selectors not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In reading post on StackOverflow about jQuery Selector performance, I keep reading the same thing over and over saying jQuery uses a **Bottom up** or **Right to Left** approach to selectors.

Take this example...

```
$("#dnsTitle a.save").removeClass("disabled");
```

According to what I have been reading it is better performance to use this instead...

```
$("a.save #dnsTitle").removeClass("disabled");
```

The problem I am running into is this does not even work at all!  Can someone clarify the real best method for doing selectors?

I am working on an existing project that has some really long selectors and I am trying to improve them where I can but it seems I am getting bad information or outdated.  I am using jQuery 2.0

Comment: css selector after any space denotes descendent of previous selector before space. Your examples show tree in reverse order from each other

Comment: Try to cache your JQuery selectors in JavaScript variables where possible to boost performance instead of traversing the DOM hierarchy each time.

Comment: You've changed the meaning of the selector... so no, it won't give the same result. The R to L just means that it starts with the right most part of the selector *(the most specific)*, selects them, then filters the set down by using the rest of the selector, walking toward the left, using each part to filter.

Comment: In the second version, you are missing a couple of quotes and a comma - `$("a.save", "#dnsTitle")`. The second argument is the so-called context, which defaults to `document`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The concept of "Bottom Up/Right to Left/Leaf to Root" is only related to the implementation of the selector parser and not the order of the selectors in usage.

### Usage:

From the usage standpoint, selectors are "read" left to right, where your first selector is your root, and the succeeding selectors your descendants. The elements that match the last selector are returned. And so:

`#dnsTitle a.save` - looks for an element that has an id of `dnsTitle` and from there, looks for a decendant `a` element with class `save`. You end up with the `a` elements with the class `save`.

`a.save #dnsTitle` - looks for an `a` element with class `save` and from that, finds a decendant with an id of `dnsTitle`. You end up with whatever elements with the id `dnsTitle`

### Parsing:

Now from the parsing point of view, there's 2 common ways you approach parsing a selector string, and they're the "Top-down" and the "Bottom-Up":

- **Top-down / Root to Leaves / Left to Right**

  If you've been through a Data Structures course, then this is how you normally parse a tree. You find the node where you want to start, which would be your first selector. Then you work your way down in finding the succeeding nodes.

  A problem in this approach is that it uses a recursive approach and uses a lot of memory, especially if your tree is huge. Also, the issue of back-tracking is a problem since the succeeding selectors are *descendants*, and matches may vary in depth. The next selector might match a *great^N* grandchild. Recursion goes N steps deep to find that great^N child and take N steps to return back up.
- **Bottom-Up / Right to Left / Leaves to Root**

  With this approach, the parser looks for all elements that match the last selector and you end up with an array of matches. With that array of matches, you filter them if they match the succeeding previous selectors.

  The advantage of this approach is that you have a fixed array to work on, and not a variable-depth tree. Also, you are filtering linearly since a node, in this case, can only have one parent in contrast to top-down which deals with multiple children. This also means you only need loops to do the job, not recursion. One loop can go over each result, and the other, nested, to go through each ancestor if it matches the succeeding previous selectors.

Comment: further to this, (#dnsTitle, a.save) would look for an element with id 'dnsTitle', AND an <a> element with class 'save'